# Jquery-Clone() append

Tags: jquery, clone

I am facing an issue whlie trying to clone a parent div and then appending it directly under itself. My function works fine as long as the last node is 
selected so:

```
 <div>
 <div> A </div>
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
   </div>
```

will result in

```
<div>
 <div> A </div>
   <div> A.1 </div> 
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
   </div>
```

If i clone A. But if I clone A again I get.

```
<div>
 <div> A </div>
   <div> A.1 </div>
 <div> A </div>
   <div> A.1 </div>
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
   </div>
```

while I would like

```
<div>
 <div> A </div>
   <div> A.1 </div>
   <div> A.1 </div>
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
   </div>
```

My markup and code are below:

```
<div id="maindiv">
 <div>
  <label>First</label> 
  <input type="button" class="repeat1" onclick="Repeat(this)"/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Second</label> 
  <input type="button" class="repeat1" onclick="Repeat(this)"/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>Third</label> 
  <input type="button" class="repeat2" onclick="Repeat(this)"/>
 </div>

</div>

function Repeat(obj)
{
 var CurrentDiv = $(obj).parents("div[class^='repeat']:first");
 $(CurrentDiv).clone().appendTo(CurrentDiv).end();

}
```

I also have a similar issue with deleting where all the child nodes are deleted while I just want a single div removed. Any help would be appreciated. The remove function is

```
function Remove(obj)
    {
     var CurrentDiv = $(obj).parents("div[class^='repeat']:first");
     CurrentDiv.remove();

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
function Repeat(obj)
{
 var currentDiv = $(obj).parent("div");
 currentDiv.clone().insertAfter(currentDiv);
}
```

UPDATE:
If you want nesting, try this:

```
<div id="maindiv">
  <ul>First
   <li>
    <label>Sub-first</label> 
    <input type="button" class="repeat1" onclick="Repeat(this)"/>
   </li>
 </ul>

 <ul>Second
  <li>
   <label>Sub-second</label> 
   <input type="button" class="repeat1" onclick="Repeat(this)"/>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <ul>Third
  <li>
   <label>Sub-third</label> 
   <input type="button" class="repeat2" onclick="Repeat(this)"/>
  </li>
 </ul>   
</div>

<script>   
function Repeat(obj)
  {
    var CurrentLi = $(obj).parent("li");
    CurrentLi.clone().insertAfter(CurrentLi);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Insert after does solve the problem but I loose the indentation that I had with appendTo.

Comment: Like SLaks mentions: your markup is messed up. The indentions that you show are arbitrary. You'll need to add another layer of DIVs (or use ULs and LIs) to get the nesting to work out.

Answer (score 1):

I think your markup is confused:

```
<div>
 <div> A </div>
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
</div>
```

using this in the body of repeat:

`$(obj).clone().text('A 1').insertAfter(obj);`

should produce:

```
<div>
 <div> A </div>
 <div>A 1</div>
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
</div>
```

Likewise using this as the body of your remove function: `$(obj).siblings('div:first').remove();`

should then do this:

```
<div>
 <div>A 1</div>
 <div> B </div>
 <div> C </div>
</div>
```

Id that what youre trying to do or ami i misunderstanding? Also what is the siginifigance of the "repeat*" class or was that a thing to use as a selector for what youre trying to implement?

Comment: The Repeat class is meant to be used as a selector. Insert After did the trick but I lost the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- (1) The way I read it, the call to $.end() is superfluous;  I believe $.end() is only useful if you're going to chain more calls after it.
- (2) It looks like you're trying to attach the clone of CurrentDiv as a direct child (not sibling) of CurrentDiv;  Since these are both  elements, I'm not sure if it makes sense.

But if it does make sense, than it's completely natural that both A and the previous clone would be cloned in the second call to Repeat().

Lastly -- just FYI, your variable and function names aren't idiomatic.  It's more customary to start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: It should be a child with respect to the format(indentation), but otherwise it is a carbon copy, independent of it's "parent". Hence I should be able to delete just one node and not the entire structure.

Comment: Deleting a node will delete its children, unless you first take pains to move those children somewhere else.