# Duplicate/clone elements from HTML form

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to duplicate the below elements from a HTML form.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label>Camera</label>
    <div class="selector">
        <input type="text" name="room1" disabled class="input-text full-width" value="1" placeholder="1">
        </input>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label>ADULTS</label>
    <div class="selector">
        <select name="adults[]" class="full-width">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label>Copii</label>
    <div class="selector">
        <select name="kids[]" class="full-width">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="age-of-children no-display">
    <h5>Varsta copii</h5>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 child-age-field">
        <label>Copil 1</label>
        <div class="selector validation-field">
            <select name="child_ages[]" class="full-width">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put a button inside the form called "Add Room". My form has a submit button also.
I never used the clone() from jQuery so I don't know where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery-Clone() append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187808/jquery-clone-append)

Comment: @Mathemats I dont want to acomplish what that answer stated.  The html from my question is one room, so i need to duplicate it and put it below after the code from my q.